# running a foreach loop through a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Hi Im still pretty new to PHP and I want to save three different things in an array that I will be pulling through my database. For now I just need help with setting up the array. For each row of the database theres 3 things I want to sort from, the week of the year(say 43), the hours i worked that week (say 29) , and the year (say 2013). So just to set up the array I put a bunch of fake data like so:

```
$hours = array(
    "week" => array(1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19,21,23,25,27,29,31,33,35,37,39,41,43,45,47,49,51), 
    "hours" => array(65,56,34,76,87,43,23,43,53,23,65,34,23,54,65,75,34,23,34,54,34,54,65,34,23,76),
     "year" => array(2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013,2013, 2014,2014,2014,2014,2014)
);
```

My first question is: Is my array set up properly for what Im trying to describe.
My second question: If it is set up correctly, how could I run a foreach loop so I can access all three variables, the week of the year, the hours, and the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see it, you need it somewhat different way.

There should be some table in a database, with a columns: `id`, `week`, `hours` and `year`.

So in php equivalent it will be:

```
$result = [
  ['id' => 1, 'week' => 1,  'hours' => 40, 'year' => 2014],
  ['id' => 2, 'week' => 3,  'hours' => 53, 'year' => 2014],
  ['id' => 3, 'week' => 14, 'hours' => 32, 'year' => 2014],
];
```

Then you can use foreach to find a certain row:

```
$target = 3; # assume target week we trying to search is 3

$row_found = null;   

foreach($result as $row) {
  if($row['week'] == $target) {
    $row_found = $row;

    break;
  }
}
```

As with your examle you it will break if your arrays by some reason will differ in size.

Additionaly, you can reindex your array by week:

```
$result = [ # that's result from mysql
  ['id' => 1, 'week' => 1,  'hours' => 40, 'year' => 2014],
  ['id' => 2, 'week' => 3,  'hours' => 53, 'year' => 2014],
  ['id' => 3, 'week' => 14, 'hours' => 32, 'year' => 2014],
];

$result_indexed = [];

foreach($result as $row) {
  $result_indexed[$row['week']] = $row;
}
```

Then a certain week can be easily accessed with `$result_indexed[3]` for example for week #3

Comment: I dont want to run the foreach loop through what I got from the database I want to add add weeks together first like week 1 +2 together, then 3+4 etc so what I want to do is have an if statement checking if the week number if the year is dividable by two using modulus and then if it is, then it means its an even week, so id that week to the previous week then put the two weeks (say it was 1 and 2) as 1 in the new array, and the hours (say 12+13) as 25 in hours of the new array

Comment: and the year would be the same for both so just lets say 2013, so the array would contain week =>1 hours => 25 and year => 2013 do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @user2989367 not quite, really, it doesn't make any sense. Could you please say what you are trying to achieve in a long run?

Comment: Okay what I have is a calendar with work days as events and each work day has the hours i worked, the week of the year, and the year. I want to calculate my paychecks, and I get paid every two weeks, so I want to add up the hours of week 1 and 2, 3 and 4 ... all the way to 51 and 52.

Comment: @user2989367 and you want to get hours for all week pairs, right?